# Should the nodes in a data structure hold a reference to an object or be the object itsself?

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, tree

I'd like to use the tree data structure for a project.

I was following along with this tutorial: [Swift Tree Data Structure](https://www.raywenderlich.com/138190/swift-algorithm-club-swift-tree-data-structure)

In this example, the nodes have a value parameter with a generic type.

```
class Node<T> {
  var value: T
  weak var parent: Node?
  var children: [Node] = []

  init(value: T) {
    self.value = value
  }

  func add(child: Node) {
    children.append(child)
    child.parent = self
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if data structures should simply hold a reference to a model object rather than being the model itsself?

i.e. If I wanted to have a data structure of a family tree, would it be better to do:

```
class Node {
  var value: Person
  weak var parent: Node?
  var children: [Node] = []

  init(value: Person) {
    self.value = value
  }

  func add(child: Node) {
    children.append(child)
    child.parent = self
  }
}

class Person {
  name: String

  init(name: String) {
    self.name
  }
}
```

Or would this be better:

```
class Person {
  let name: String
  weak var parent: Person?
  var children: [Person] = []

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = 
  }

  func add(child: Person) {
    children.append(child)
    child.parent = self
  }
}
```

I can imagine that separating the model and structure is helpful but then I can also imagine it making some functionality more difficult e.g. syncing with the cloud.

Comment: I don't really see the purpose of the first option (Node), do you wan't to generalize and use it for something else too?

Comment: No, don't need to generalize.

Comment: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) Then I would bother making it with a template, just go for something like your second option